# C++ Must take either one or zero argument error (Operator+)

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have the following statement in my Hour.cpp file: (after class Hour)

```
Hour Hour ::operator+(const Hour& h1, const Hour& h2) const{
    return Hour(h1.getHour()+ h2.getHour(), h1.getMinute() + h2.getMinute(), h1.getSecond() + h2.getSecond());
}
```

However, after running it I get:

```
error:  must take either zero or one argument
```

Comment: Because you are implementing `operator+` as a member, the first operand is `this` so you only need 1 argument for the second operand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While overloading an operator as a member function, you can only another class as a second operand. The first operand is the object of the class itself. So, you have two options:

- You can modify the overloading function as

```
Hour Hour::operator+(const Hour& h) const{
    return Hour(hour_ + h.getHour(), minute_ + h.getMinute(), seconds_ + h.getSecond());
}

where hour_, minute_, seconds_ are member variables of Hour class.
```

- Do not implement as a member function

```
Hour operator+(const Hour& h1, const Hour& h2) const{
    return Hour(h1.getHour()+ h2.getHour(), h1.getMinute() + h2.getMinute(), h1.getSecond() + h2.getSecond());
}
```